# Grails select with null

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a simple select tag in my gsp for a dropdown which is populated from another table. Recently I have been getting null pointer exception on the dropdown page and I found out it was because a null value was entered in the table from the which the dropdown was getting populated, i.e `optionKey="name"` the `name` column in that other table had a null value.

How do I avoid my entire page crashing due to this single null entry?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
optionKey="${{it.name ?: "whateveryouwanthere"}}"
```

Comment: Just one problem, when I use the above expression instead of 'name' directly, the value getting saved is the toString value, not the name value

Comment: This will end up as a string in an option html element. It has to resolve to a string. What datatype is `name`?

Comment: name is of String type

Comment: ... so how could the `.toString()` method on a `String` be different than the value of the given string?